# Spring data support to create tables using java entities

Tags: cassandra, spring-boot, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring data Cassandra, to connect with Cassandra database, with configuration file extending AbstractCassandraConfiguration and overriding functions -

```
@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
}

@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[] {"com.example"};
}
```

My aim is to create tables automatically in Cassandra from the mentioned entities in com.example package with @Table annotation.
For example -

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table(value="goal")
public class Goal {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    private String description;

    public Goal(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Goal() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Goals [id=" + id + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }

}
```

For this entity, with the given configuration, one table should get created during spring initialization, But it fails to do so.
No exception though, It just doesn't create anything in Cassandra.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When using Spring Boot, this does not work out of the box yet. There's an open ticket (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4886) for this issue, maybe you want to cast your vote.

Comment: Careful, generally it is a bad idea to let an application *automagically* generates schema for you. Schema and data model are crucial for the success of your apps with Cassandra so take care of it yourself

Comment: Hi @mp911de , Thanks for the comment. But I think changing the **SchemaAction** property should work. I am already creating the bean of **BasicCassandraMappingContext**, So Ideally It should work.
Is there any workaround to auto-create the tables from entities as of now ?

Comment: Thanks @doanduyhai for the suggestion, But I am using this for development and testing purpose, not for production. While moving my app to production, I will create scripts file to create and update the schema.

Comment: If you're using for test, consider switching to www.achilles.io. We have full support for JUnit with embedded Cassandra for testing. Disclose: I'm the creator of Achilles

Comment: Thanks, @doanduyhai . Achilles is awesome. You have many features and customizations which make developers life easy. But I have a question here, does it slow down our application performance-wise? Because there are many customizations you have done on top of Cassandra. Also,  Can we use **Achilles** in production also or this is for test purpose only?

Comment: Achilles is used in production by several companies. About performance, because Achilles **generates source code** at compile time, there is **no proxy** at runtime so the performance overhead is very small

Comment: Thanks @doanduyhai for the details. I will try that. But I am still wondering why this is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not working" ?

Comment: @doanduyhai, I meant whatever I am trying, the above code snippet in the question, why that is not working? Am I missing something?

Comment: No idea, maybe you can drop a question on the Spring Data Cassandra mailing list

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar requirement and following works for me:-

```
@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
    cluster.setPort(9042);
    return cluster;
}    
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[] { "com.user.entity" };
}

protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return "user_db";
}

public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
}
```

Once your context is up, you can check the table in cassandra.
It is assumed your keyspace is already created in cassandra.
Please inform if you also want to create keyspace on the fly.

Comment: I am just trying to understand, How is this different from what I was trying.
I tried - 
    **SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;**
And this didn't worked.

Can you please explain this.